# Inverse of $h(x) = 1 + x - \sqrt{1+2x}$

Tags: calculus, inverse

I want to compute the inverse of

$$h(x) = 1 + x - \sqrt{1+2x}$$
for $x > 0$. To do so I have started from

$$\begin{align}y = 1 + x -\sqrt{1+2x} \iff \\  y -1 =  x -\sqrt{1+2x} \stackrel{y=1+2x>0}{\iff} \iff \\ 2\sqrt{y} - y + 1 +4x=0 \stackrel{u=\sqrt{y}}{\iff} \\ u^2 -2u - (1+4x) = 0\end{align}$$

which has roots

$$u_{1,2}=\begin{cases}
1 + \sqrt{2}\sqrt{1+2x}\\
1 - \sqrt{2}\sqrt{1+2x}
\end{cases}$$

Working backwards, i.e., using $u=\sqrt{y}$ and $y=1+2x$ I do not get the desired result$^{\dagger}$. Could you please someone cast some light?

<sup>$\dagger$ I know that the inversion is $h^{-1}(y) = y+\sqrt{2y}$, for $y>0$.</sup>

Comment: are you sure about your process? your second equation states that something to the square is equals to a negative number.

Comment: You can't square both  sides if one is negative and the other is not. Also, find where the inverse exists

Comment: When I obtained a quadratic in $x$, its discriminant was $8y$. You probably just made a simple algebra mistake.

Comment: I made an edit to address the comments. Any additional comments are highly appreciated.

Comment: Your post was clearer before your edit. Try editing again to show your procedure more clearly.

Comment: As of your latest edit, you seem to be mixing up multiple definitions of $y$. Ideally you should obtain $x^2-2xy+y^2-2y=0$.

Comment: Are you sure that inverse means inverse function and not the multiplicative inverse, using $h=\frac{x^2}{1+x+\sqrt{1+2x}}$?

Comment: Yes the result I need is $x=y+\sqrt{2y}$ which is shown by @egreg. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First solve for $x$ in
$$
y=x+1-\sqrt{1+2x}
$$
Isolating the square root
$$
\sqrt{1+2x}=x+1-y
$$
Squaring we get
$$
1+2x=x^2+1+y^2+2x-2xy-2y
$$
Hence
$$
x^2-2xy-2y+y^2=0
$$
This quadratic solves as
$$
x=y\pm\sqrt{2y}
$$
and we need to choose the right branch.

OK, this is not really obvious. Let's take another path. For $x>0$ we have $f(x)>0$. Indeed, the inequality $x+1>\sqrt{1+2x}$ is the same as $x^2>0$, which is true. Rewrite the equation as
$$
y+\sqrt{1+2x}=x+1
$$
and square (which doesn't introduce spurious solutions):
$$
y^2+2y\sqrt{1+2x}+1+2x=x^2+2x+1
$$
that becomes
$$
2y\sqrt{2x+1}=x^2-y^2
$$
Thus we see we need $x>y$. This is never satisfied by $x=y-\sqrt{2y}$, but is by $x=y+\sqrt{2y}$.

Thus the inverse is $g(x)=x+\sqrt{2x}$.

Comment: The OP made it clear that the function is considered for $x>0$ where it is invertible.

Comment: @jjagmath Overlooked it, sorry.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How the term $\sqrt{1+2x}$ disappears in $2y=x^2-y^2$.

Comment: @darkmoor Because I forgot it. :-)