# Inverse of $\psi(t) = \frac{\nu}{c^2}h(\frac{ct}{\nu})$ with $h(x) = 1 + x - \sqrt{1+2x}$

Tags: calculus, inverse-function

Given the inverse of $$h(x) = 1 + x - \sqrt{1+2x},$$ [i.e.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4436821/inverse-of-hx-1-x-sqrt12x), $$h^{-1}(y)=y+\sqrt{2y},$$ I am trying to compute the inverse of $$\psi(t) = \frac{\nu}{c^2}h(\frac{ct}{\nu}).$$ My first step was to define $g(u) = \frac{c}{\nu}u$ and invert the composition $$(h\circ g)^{-1}(u) = (g^{-1} \circ h^{-1})(u) = \frac{\nu}{c}u + \frac{\nu}{c}\sqrt{2u}.$$ Then, using the same rule, I have tried

$$\psi^{-1}(u) = \frac{c^2}{\nu}h^{-1}(u) = \frac{c^2}{\nu} \frac{\nu}{c}u + \frac{c^2}{\nu} \frac{\nu}{c}\sqrt{2u} = c u +c \sqrt{2u}.$$ I know that the result is

$$\psi^{-1}(u) = \sqrt{2\nu v}+cu.$$ Could you please someone cast some light on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The second term should be $\frac{\nu}{c}\sqrt{2\frac{c^2}{\nu}u}=\sqrt{2\nu u}$, not $\frac{\nu}{c}\frac{c^2}{\nu}\sqrt{2u}$. Both expressions are obtainable by applying... more than just two functions, starting from $u$. You may have messed up the need to completely reverse that sequence.

Comment: @J.G. Could you please provide some details on how $(h\circ g)^{-1}(u)$ should be?

Comment: From $t$ to $\psi$ you apply a multiplication, $h$ and another multiplication, so you need to invert three steps viz. $(i\circ h\circ g)^{-1}=g^{-1}\circ h^{-1}\circ i^{-1}$, and $t=\frac{\nu}{c}h^{-1}\left(\frac{c^2}{\nu}\psi\right)$.

Comment: Is the $i(t) = \frac{\nu}{c^2}t$ and $g(t) = \frac{c}{v}t$ so as $\psi(t) = (i \circ h \circ g)(t)$?

Comment: Then $$\psi^{-1}(t) = (i \circ h \circ g)^{-1}(t) = g^{-1}(h^{-1}(i^{-1}(t)))=g^{-1}(h^{-1}(\frac{c^2}{\nu}t)) = g^{-1}(\frac{c^2}{\nu}t + \sqrt{2\frac{c^2}{\nu}t}) = \frac{\nu}{c}(\frac{c^2}{\nu}t + \sqrt{2t\frac{c^2}{\nu}})=ct+\sqrt{2t\nu} ?$$ Could you please verify the computations? I feel that there is an abuse of notation in using the $t$ variable. Shall I use $u = \psi(t)$ and express the above equation w.r.t. $u$? That is, $t = \psi^{-1}(u) = \dots = cu+\sqrt{2\nu u}$?

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea. Since we're inverting a relation expressing $\psi$ in terms of $t$, you expect the final result to be $t$ in terms of $\psi$, viz. $\psi=\psi(t)\implies t=\psi^{-1}(\psi)$; or, to make that less confusing by having $\psi$ be a function only, $u=\psi(t)\implies t=\psi^{-1}(u)$. With such a convention, your calculations correctly deduce$$u=\frac{\nu}{c^2}h\left(\frac{c}{\nu}t\right)\implies t=cu+\sqrt{2\nu u}.$$

Comment: Thanks. The last time I inverted functions was in high school more that 15 years ago. You helped me to remember a few things.